# Really Need an advice for my use case diagram. I am trying to model a use case for the next objective:

Tags: uml

[image]

Am I right in my use case or does it need some corrections?

Answer (score 1):

A few things should be changed:

- `Login` is no use case (no added value; read Bittner/Spence). Rather it is a constraint and should be linked to the UC with `{ login required }`.
- `Withdrawal`, `Deposit`, ... need to be named predicate, subject; e.g. `Withdraw money`.
- Finally `Transaction` (should be `Perform transaction`) should probably be a primary UC linked to the actor. I don't know the exact requirements, though.

I usually try to avoid include/extend as it's an attempt to perform functional decomposition. Rather I stay with single, unique added values represented by a single bubble. That's putting the focus on the added value (which is the important thing for UCs) and not on functions (which shall be dealt at class level later in the design phase). From a user perspective it's not a transaction which can either be deposit/withdrawal or so, but the latter are the "the main important things".

Comment: How do you think, which requirements should I Clarify?

Comment: Making the whole context clear would be tough. Try to grasp the essence of the last paragraph. Or even better: read Bittner/Spence.

Comment: Well, SO is no tutorial place, so I can not start a discussion as to what needs to be done and what shouldn't. However, if you come up with a new single specific question you are welcome to open a new one.